# Clean up/Burninate [clip] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, clean-up

There are 328 questions tagged [clip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clip). It doesn't have a wiki/excerpt. It doesn't have any followers. It is mostly used with a variety of other tags to mention audio clips or video clips or the act of clipping like clipping images, maps, audio and video or about the clip property in [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clip+css) as mentioned by [Jason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287218/clean-up-burninate-clip-tag?noredirect=1#comment161289_287218).

I think for for audio and video clips clipping tag is not necessary and just [audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/audio) and [video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/video) tags will do.

For clipping related questions there is already a [clipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clipping) tag and it has a wiki/excerpt and 5 followers.

I think the CSS clip property related questions can have a [css-clip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-clip) tag.

Some other related tags

- [clips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clips) - Its about a programming framework which is sometimes [misused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28689235/2246380) and might need some clean up.
- [movieclip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movieclip) - Its about an object related to Adobe Flash which is [sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmovieclip%5D%20%20-flash%20is%3Aquestion%20-actionscript%20-%5Bactionscript-3%5D%20-%5Bflash-cs5%5D%20-%5Bflash%5D%20-%5Bactionscript-2%5D%20) [misused](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28800627/2246380) and also might need some clean up.

So what do you guys think? Should it just be cleaned up or both cleaned up and burninated?

Comment: What to do about [CSS clip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clip+css)?

Comment: You mean you want to clip it down? ;)